# Assumptions aren't working in this sum

Tags: summation, assumptions

I have a sum that should be real:

```
FullSimplify@Sum[1/(α n^4 + β), {n, 1, ∞}, Assumptions 
-> α > 0 && β > 0]
```

But the result have involved even roots of -1, so I'm not sure what is going on:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Eventually, after trying many other things I got an answer:

```
FullSimplify@Refine[ComplexExpand@Sum[1/(α n^4 + β), {n, 1, 
∞}], α > 0 && β > 0]
```

[image]

But I'd like to know why the first approach didn't work? Seems to me like there are too many ways of adding assumptions into the expression.

Comment: In which sense it didn't work ?

Comment: I added the assumptions that alpha and beta are Real. So the sum should be real, but the result contains complex numbers: (-1)^4 or (1 + I) / Sqrt[2].

Comment: Representations of real numbers or functions can contain imaginary numbers. All of the imaginary components cancel out leaving a purely real result (although numerical calculations may have small imaginary components if calculations are not done with infinite precision--see [Chop](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html)). However, finding a representation without any "intermediate" complex components can be difficult or impossible. `ComplexExpand` will frequently help.

Comment: With ref. to Bob's rmk., try: `Assuming[α > 0 && β > 0,
 FullSimplify@ ComplexExpand[
   FullSimplify@ Sum[1/(α n^4 + β), {n, 1, ∞}, Assumptions -> α > 0 && β> 0], 
   TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] ]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, do know you why the Assumptions need to be put in two places? because the inner assumption seems to do nothing  `Assuming[\[Alpha] > 0 && \[Beta] > 0, 
 FullSimplify@
  ComplexExpand[
   FullSimplify@Sum[1/(\[Alpha] n^4 + \[Beta]), {n, 1, \[Infinity]}], 
   TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]]`

Comment: @M.R. The outside `Assuming` affects `FullSimplify` and anything inside it (making the `Assumptions` inside `Sum` unnecessary). The inner assumption itself affects only the operation of `Sum` but not of `FullSimplify`. I should have noticed that with `Assuming` the `Sum` option `Assumptions` could be omitted.